# Eloquent select with join and not exists in raw statement

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I need to write select statement like that:

```
SELECT co.id FROM client_order co 
                INNER JOIN client_order_status cos ON cos.id = co.order_status_id AND cos.name IN ('for_shipping', 'to_be_shipped_later') 
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dpackage dp WHERE dp.order_id = co.id AND dp.is_spec_label_generated = 1) 
                ORDER BY co.id
```

In `Eloquent` my expression looks like that:

```
  $clientOrderEntities = ClientOrder::join('client_order_status', 'client_order_status.id', '=', 'order_status_id')
                ->whereIn('client_order_status.name', ['for_shipping', 'to_be_shipped_later'])
                ->whereNotExists(function($query) use($orderId) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                        ->from('dpackage')
                        ->where([
                            ['order_id', '=', $orderId]
                            ['is_spec_label_generated', '=', 1]
                        ]);
                })->get();
```

I don't know how to pass orderId from first part of query into `whereNotExists` sub query

---

At the moment it looks:

```
$clientOrderEntities = ClientOrder::join('client_order_status', 'client_order_status.id', '=', 'order_status_id')
                ->whereIn('client_order_status.name', ['for_shipping', 'to_be_shipped_later'])
                ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                        ->from('dpackage')
                        ->where([
                            ['order_id', '=', 'client_order.id'],
                            ['is_spec_label_generated', '=', 1]
                        ]);
                })
                ->select('client_order.*')
                ->get();
```

---

This query works:

```
$clientOrderEntities = ClientOrder::join('client_order_status', 'client_order_status.id', '=', 'order_status_id')
                ->whereIn('client_order_status.name', ['for_shipping', 'to_be_shipped_later'])
                ->whereRaw(' NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dpackage dp WHERE dp.order_id = client_order.id AND dp.is_spec_label_generated = 1) ')
                ->select('client_order.*')
                ->get();
```

---

This query works too and is faster than eloquent statements, as @Newbie wrotes, but I don't know why his answer has been deleted:

```
$clientOrderEntities = DB::select('SELECT co.* FROM client_order co INNER JOIN client_order_status cos ON cos.id = co.order_status_id AND cos.name IN ("for_shipping", "to_be_shipped_later") WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dpackage dp WHERE dp.order_id = co.id AND dp.is_spec_label_generated = 1) ');
```

Comment: Which error you are getting now?

Comment: There is no error, but it return two rows again the only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe defining name for the tables help you with this.

```
$clientOrderEntities = \DB::table('client_order as co')
    ->join('client_order_status as cos', 'cos.id', '=', 'co.order_status_id')
    ->whereIn('cos.name', ['for_shipping', 'to_be_shipped_later'])
    ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('dpackage')
            ->where([
                ['order_id', '=', 'co.id'],
                ['is_spec_label_generated', '=', 1]
                ]);
        })->get();
```

Comment: It returns two rows while raw query returns only one row, because the second row has column is_spec_label_generated set to 1, there is maybe a way to write above query using only raw statement ?

Comment: @Jonson I haven't caught your meaning. Are you looking for a way to execute the raw query?